# How to improve the segmentation of the Lungs without Deep Learning

Tags: python, image-processing, image-segmentation, scikit-image, medical

My objective is to obtain the **Logical OR of the ROI of the lungs along slices axis Per Voxel** from a Lungs 3D CT-Scans using **fast conventional approaches**.

I have tried to use different approaches, such as **thresholding and morphology**, and **watershed**,
but the results are not perfect as you can see in the image down.

I took the logical OR of the whole masks per voxel to be compared with the resultant output of my manipulations, and took the standard deviation of the voxels along the slices axis to extract the ROI depending on it.

#### My question is:

How can I make the Result looks very close to the masks after logical OR ??

The used Dataset (images, and masks) is [Here](https://zenodo.org/record/3757476#.Xs_HgMBS82x).

[image: Result] in the following code, and tried to combine thresholding, and morphology, but the problem is that:

```
# import necessary libraries
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
# plt.switch_backend('Qt5Agg')
import glob
import nibabel as nib
from skimage.io import imsave
from skimage.filters import threshold_otsu
from skimage.transform import resize
import skimage.morphology as morph
from skimage import measure, exposure , segmentation
from scipy import ndimage
#---------------------------------------------------------------
# Images
path = 'Nifti_DataSet/COVID-19-CT-Seg_20cases'
Dataset = glob.glob( os.path.join(path, '*.gz') )
# Masks
masks_path = 'Nifti_DataSet/Lung_and_Infection_Mask'
masks_Dataset = glob.glob( os.path.join(masks_path, '*.gz') )
#---------------------------------------------------------------
# Source: https://www.kaggle.com/threedb/improved-lung-segmentation-using-watershed
#---------------------------------------------------------------
def generate_markers(image,thr):
    #Creation of the internal Marker
    marker_internal = (image < thr*image.max()).reshape(image.shape)
    marker_internal
    marker_internal = segmentation.clear_border(marker_internal)
    marker_internal_labels = measure.label(marker_internal)
    areas = [r.area for r in measure.regionprops(marker_internal_labels)]
    areas.sort()
    if len(areas) > 2:
        for region in measure.regionprops(marker_internal_labels):
            if region.area < areas[-2]:
                for coordinates in region.coords:                
                       marker_internal_labels[coordinates[0], coordinates[1]] = 0
    marker_internal = marker_internal_labels > 0
    #Creation of the external Marker
    external_a = ndimage.binary_dilation(marker_internal, iterations=10)
    external_b = ndimage.binary_dilation(marker_internal, iterations=55)
    marker_external = external_b ^ external_a
    #Creation of the Watershed Marker matrix
    marker_watershed = np.zeros((512, 512), dtype=np.int)
    marker_watershed += marker_internal * 255
    marker_watershed += marker_external * 128

    return marker_internal, marker_external, marker_watershed
#================================================================================        
def get_best_th(image):
    seg = np.zeros_like(image)
    for th in range(10):
        th = th/10
        m_internal,m_external, _ = generate_markers(image,th)
        if( (np.sum(m_external) > np.sum(m_internal)) and (np.sum(m_internal) > np.sum(seg))):
            seg = m_internal
            #print(th)
    return seg
#=====================================
def generate_watershed_segmentation(img):
    img2 = exposure.equalize_hist(img)
    segm = get_best_th(img2)
    segm = np.array(segm)
    segm = np.clip(segm,0,255)
    return segm
#===============================================================
# 
# Set a Counter 
ctr = 1
#---------------------------------------------------------------
for image in Dataset:
    # Load the images as nd-arrays
    images = nib.load(image).get_fdata()
    # Resize the images
    masks = resize(images, (256,256))
    # Load the masks as nd-arrays
    masks  = nib.load(os.path.join(masks_path,os.path.basename(image))).get_fdata() 
    # Resize the masks
    masks = resize(masks, (256,256))
    # make logical or for all the masks along slices axis
    masks = masks.any(axis=2)
    # print(masks.shape)
    # Take the Std Deviation for all the images along slices axis
    std = np.std(images, axis=2)
    stdcp = std.copy()
    # suppress the low values
    std[std < 0.1 * np.max(std)] = 0.0
    # Normalize The Output
    image = 1. * std / np.max(std)
    # Threshold the result
    val = threshold_otsu(image-std)
    image2 = (image-std) < val
    # Threshold again after masking with the previous result
    val2 = threshold_otsu(image2*image*(image-std))
    result = (image2*image*(image-std)) < val2
    #-------------------------------------------
    #           Morphology Part
    #===========================================
    # Structuring Element
    radius = 5
    # SE = morph.disk(radius)
    SE = morph.star(radius)
    # SE = morph.diamond(radius)
    #-------------------------------------------
    #        Morphological Operations
    #-------------------------------------------
    res2 = morph.binary_erosion(result,selem=SE)
    res2 = morph.remove_small_objects(res2)
    # res2 = morph.binary_opening(res2,selem=SE)
    res2 = morph.label(res2)
    #---------Largest Connected Component--------------------
    lab = np.argmax(np.unique(res2,return_counts=True)[1][1:])
    lab +=1
    res2[res2!=lab] = 0
    res2 = res2.astype(np.uint8)
    # ----More Morphological operations---------
    res2 = morph.remove_small_holes(res2)
    #-------------------------------------------
    res3 = generate_watershed_segmentation(stdcp)
    #-------------------------------------------
    #        Visualize the Results
    #-------------------------------------------
    plt.figure(num='image_%d'%ctr)

    plt.subplot('221')
    plt.imshow(masks)
    plt.title('masks after Logical OR')
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.subplot('222')
    plt.imshow(result)
    plt.title('after first stage')
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.subplot('223')
    plt.imshow(res2)
    plt.title('Result')
    plt.axis('off')   
    plt.subplot('224')
    plt.imshow(res3)
    plt.title('watershed')
    plt.axis('off')  
    # figManager = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
    # figManager.window.showMaximized()
    plt.show()
    #-----------------
    # Increase the counter
    ctr+=1
```

Comment: Your problem is not very clear to me. Would you like to improve your lung segmentation?

Comment: @JoOkuma I do like to make the results looks like the original std deviation taken along slices axis, so I can crop my dataset according to that ROI, before to use deep learning

Comment: I don't think it is clear yet. I'm not sure what the standard deviation has to do with the segmentation. Regarding the segmentation, I suggest you take a look at this article (https://aapm.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/mp.13773?casa_token=HQV8BGJDgbIAAAAA%3AIVoWeecDaPvQBdEVhEp_Xl6vN6w08yYr5EiXEKdcTxhvNWrn585dXi49L4fN88zmV29vAzca5OWukt4), they have a binary avaliable which could be useful.